# nodeJS localstorage getting values

Tags: javascript, node.js, local-storage

There's a key in browser's localstorage named userToken and I'm trying to get it so I can decode using my private key.

I'm using a package called node-localstorage which can be found here
https://github.com/lmaccherone/node-localstorage

But it returns `null`

What could be the problem here?

```
app.get('/getitnow', function(req,res) {
    var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
    var localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('userToken'));

});
```

Comment: This won't access browser's LocalStorage. How do you think this should work at all? What you need to do is to send a request from client to the server with the token.

Comment: `What you need to do is to send a request from client to the server with the token.` userToken (key) already exists, what I want to do is to get its value. If I don't know its value, how could I send a request from the client to the server?

Comment: You can't get the value from browser localstorage using server-side code. You retrieve the token on the client and send it to the server.

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks. I'll answer it in a few mins.

Comment: can u please post the answer...

Answer (score 0):

`localstorage` are browser dependent, NodeJs is server side.

Try using session:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: '12345'}));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not gonna get the values from client. node-localstorage is localstorage for node. That's why it returns null because you haven't set any values on directory scratch.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/getitnow', (req,res)=> {
    var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
    var localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');
    localStorage.setItem('userToken', yourToken)//if you are sending token. 
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('userToken'));
});
```

Node.js works on server side so client side localStorage won't work here. If you posting a form to node(express) side.

```
app.post('/getitnow', (req,res)=> {
        var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
        var localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');
        localStorage.setItem('userToken', req.body.userToken)//if you are sending token. 
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('userToken'));
    });
```

and your post form would be look like this.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="/getitnow">
    <input type="hidden" name="userToken" value="eyGjasdkfasdfe4eafafsf0..."> //name should be must
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```